# Can't get dropwizard app to work with swagger-ui

Tags: dropwizard, swagger-ui

I'm having a hard time getting Swagger UI to work with my dropwizard application. The annotated dropwizard app seems to generate the correct json documents but swagger UI is unabel to navigate it properly.
Main API page, generated at http://localhost:8080/v1/TimeService/api-docs:

```
{"apiVersion":"0.0","swaggerVersion":"1.2","apis":[{"path":"/times"}]}
```

Swagger displays that page correctly.
Detail information for the time resource generated at http://localhost:8080/v1/TimeService/api-docs/times:

```
{"apiVersion":"0.0","swaggerVersion":"1.2","basePath":"/v1/TimeService/*","resourcePath":"/times","produces":["application/json"],"apis":[{"path":"/times/","operations":[{"method":"GET","summary":"Retrieves time for given","notes":"timezone parameter is optional, defaults to GMT","type":"array","items":{"$ref":"Time"},"nickname":"getTime","parameters":[{"name":"timezone","description":"timezone","required":false,"items":{"type":"string"},"paramType":"query","allowMultiple":false}]}]}],"models":{"Time":{"id":"Time","properties":{"time":{"type":"string"}}}}}
```

Which looks good to me. But whenever, in the swagger UI, I click on any "times" hyperlink to display the details, nothing happens. It looks like swagger ui cannot resolve the link correctly.

My annotated resource, TimeResource.java:

```
package com.cgi.saas.bluprint;

import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

@Path("/times")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Api("/times")
public class TimeResource {
    private final String defaultTimezone;

    public TimeResource(String defaultTimezone) {
        this.defaultTimezone = defaultTimezone;
    }

    @GET
    @ApiOperation(value = "Retrieves time for given",
    notes = "timezone parameter is optional, defaults to GMT",
    response = Time.class,
    responseContainer = "List")
    @Path("/")
    public Time getTime(@ApiParam(value="timezone") @QueryParam("timezone") Optional<String> timezone) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone.or(defaultTimezone));
        formatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        String formatted = formatter.format(new Date());
        return new Time(formatted);
    }
}
```

The main service class, TimeService.java:

```
package com.cgi.saas.bluprint;

import java.util.EnumSet;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter;

import com.wordnik.swagger.config.ConfigFactory;
import com.wordnik.swagger.config.ScannerFactory;
import com.wordnik.swagger.config.SwaggerConfig;
import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsScanner;
import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiDeclarationProvider;
import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON;
import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ResourceListingProvider;
import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.reader.DefaultJaxrsApiReader;
import com.wordnik.swagger.reader.ClassReaders;

import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.assets.AssetsBundle;
import io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;



public class TimeService extends Application<TimezoneConfiguration> {

    private void configureCors(Environment environment) {
        final Dynamic filter = environment.servlets().addFilter("CORS",
                CrossOriginFilter.class);
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
        filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
        filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER, "*");
        filter.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders",
        "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Length,Accept,Origin");
        filter.setInitParameter("allowCredentials", "true");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TimeService().run(args);
    }


    public void initialize(Bootstrap<TimezoneConfiguration> timezoneConfigurationBootstrap) {
        timezoneConfigurationBootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/", "/", "index.html"));
        timezoneConfigurationBootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/swagger", "/swagger", "index.html", "swagger"));
    }

    @Override
    public void run(TimezoneConfiguration appConfig, Environment environment) throws Exception {

        DefaultServerFactory sf = (DefaultServerFactory) appConfig.getServerFactory();
        String rootPath = "/v1/" + appConfig.getDeployName() + "/*";
        sf.setJerseyRootPath(rootPath);

        configureCors(environment);     

        String defaultTimezone = appConfig.getDefaultTimezone();
        TimeResource timeResource = new TimeResource(defaultTimezone);

        environment.jersey().register(timeResource);
        // Swagger Resource
        environment.jersey().register(new ApiListingResourceJSON());

        // Swagger providers
        environment.jersey().register(new ApiDeclarationProvider());
        environment.jersey().register(new ResourceListingProvider());

        // Swagger Scanner, which finds all the resources for @Api Annotations
        ScannerFactory.setScanner(new DefaultJaxrsScanner());

        // Add the reader, which scans the resources and extracts the resource information
        ClassReaders.setReader(new DefaultJaxrsApiReader());

        // Set the swaggeonfigurationBootstrap
        final SwaggerConfig swConfig = ConfigFactory.config();

        swConfig.setBasePath(rootPath);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cgi.saas.bluprint</groupId>
    <artifactId>Application2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <dropwizard.version>0.9.0-SNAPSHOT</dropwizard.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-jersey</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>               
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.cgi.saas.bluprint.TimeService</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote it as follows:

1. Cloned the latest and greatest version of swagger-ui at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui.git
2. Copied dist under src/main/resources/swagger/assets
3. Updated pom.xml:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
       <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
       <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.federecio</groupId>
       <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
       <version>0.6</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. Updated TimeService.java:

   ```
    import java.util.EnumSet;

    import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;

    import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration.Dynamic;

    import org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter;

    import io.dropwizard.Application;

    import io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory;

    import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;

    import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;

    import io.federecio.dropwizard.swagger.SwaggerDropwizard;




   public class TimeService extends Application<TimezoneConfiguration> {


   private final SwaggerDropwizard swaggerDropwizard = new SwaggerDropwizard();

   private void configureCors(Environment environment) {
       final Dynamic filter = environment.servlets().addFilter("CORS",
               CrossOriginFilter.class);
       filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
       filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
       filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
       filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER, "*");
       filter.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders",
               "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Length,Accept,Origin");
       filter.setInitParameter("allowCredentials", "true");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       new TimeService().run(args);
   }


   public void initialize(Bootstrap<TimezoneConfiguration> timezoneConfigurationBootstrap) {
       swaggerDropwizard.onInitialize(timezoneConfigurationBootstrap);
   }

   @Override
   public void run(TimezoneConfiguration appConfig, Environment environment) throws Exception {

       DefaultServerFactory sf = (DefaultServerFactory) appConfig.getServerFactory();
       String rootPath = "/v1/" + appConfig.getDeployName() + "/*";
       sf.setJerseyRootPath(rootPath);

       configureCors(environment);     

       String defaultTimezone = appConfig.getDefaultTimezone();
       TimeResource timeResource = new TimeResource(defaultTimezone);        
       environment.jersey().register(timeResource);

       swaggerDropwizard.onRun(appConfig, environment, "localhost");
   }
   ```

   }

   5. The swagger ui is available at http://localhost:8080/v1/TimeService/swagger